# Convert element into array

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I display 5 values ​​for each loop but what I'm trying to do is put these 5 values ​​in a array but I do not see how I could do it...
For information, in my Json i have 2 element for push the different value

I tried to use the function push but the problem is that it pushes me all the values ​​in the table whereas it has to push only 5

```
    last = []
    cw.getMetricStatistics(params2, function(err, data) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    }
    else{        
    for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
        tableau = data.Datapoints[i].Average;
        console.log(tableau);
        last.push(tableau);
        console.log("last"+last);

    }

    console.log("\n");

    }



    });
```

Actual results:

10 14 18 30 5

8 54 2 45 2

Last [10,14,18,30,5,8,54,2,45,2]

Expected result:

[10,14,18,30,5]

[8,54,2,45,2]

Comment: Can you post the `data` json in your question too and if there is any sensitive information in the data, just replaced it with dummy text.

Comment: 1.    console.log(data.Datapoints[i].Average);
        tableau = data.Datapoints[i].Average;
 3.    console.log(tableau);                                                                                                                        How come line 1 and 3 produce different output?    


10 14 18 30 5
8 54 2 45 2

Comment: use `array.split(' ')` to get desired result

Comment: This let averageAsArray = data.Datapoints.map(e => e.Average) would create an array the same size as data.Datapoints containing only the Average value.

Comment: Thanks :), it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cw.getMetricStatistics(params2, function(err, data) {
if (err){
    console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
}
else{        
for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
    tableau = data.Datapoints[i].Average;
    console.log(tableau);
    let averageAsArray = data.Datapoints.map(e => e.Average);
    console.log(averageAsArray);

}

console.log("\n");

}



});
```